# Adding a variable for each Simple product within a Bundle in Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, product, simple-product, bundle

In our Magento store (1.9 CE) we have some Simple products which fit multiple applications.
So we want to create a Bundle product for each application and include the Simples in them.
The problem lies that we need a layer of data to explain the position/info for that part in that application. This varies depending on the Bundle so we can't store this data in the Simple product.
eg: Simple 'A' goes into Bundle '1' and '2'
In Bundle '1', 'A' is 'Front' but in Bundle '2', 'A' is 'Rear'
So we need a way of storing a value for each instance of a Simple product within a Bundle.

So if it's practical we need a way of adding this data in to each instance of a Simple product in a Bundle 
[image: bundle simple variable admin]

then we can pull that on the front end
[image: bundle simple variable front end]

Is it practical to input and store data at this level of the bundle? Would it end up in **catalog_product_bundle_selection** ?

Comment: Not saying this is the answer, but looking at the data that is already provided but not in use- couldn't you use the position attribute to determine where each simple goes?